# Mac application signing failed after uploading on remote server

Tags: macos, qt, signature, osx-gatekeeper

Hi I'm working on an application that uses Qt.

We were on Qt 5.4 for months and we decided to move on the latest version (5.6). Before that, we had no problem with the Mac application signature, we ran `macdeployqt` binary to deploy the application then ran a script to sign the whole package and add it to a .dmg.

Since we move to Qt 5.6, the signature process throws no error and when I try the package on other computers with an USB key, the signature is ok and the application can be launch with no problem.

But when I upload the app on Internet (Dropbox, Slack or personnal remote server), the signature is broken and it displays [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOW6G.png).

When I run `codesign --deep --verify --verbose=4 -d` and `spctl --verbose=4 --assess --type execute` before and after the upload/download it has the same output !

```
MyApp.app: accepted
source=Developer ID

Executable=/Users/digitalessence/Desktop/HeavyM.app/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
Identifier=fr.digitalessence.heavym
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=31704 flags=0x0(none) hashes=985+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=052009496d7193aed38e60269a59c6bcd386f799
CandidateCDHash sha256=bc721c8b50f4e231a724f524083ca8689108b14a
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CDHash=bc721c8b50f4e231a724f524083ca8689108b14a
Signature size=8918
Authority=Developer ID Application: Digital Essence (NZ8539HN33)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=24 May 2016 15:36:07
Info.plist entries=9
TeamIdentifier=NZ8539HN33
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=33
Nested=Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework
Nested=Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework
Nested=PlugIns/audio/libqtaudio_coreaudio.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib
Nested=Frameworks/QtDBus.framework
Nested=PlugIns/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqicns.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqtga.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqdds.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/mediaservice/libqtmedia_audioengine.dylib
Nested=Frameworks/QtCore.framework
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib
Nested=Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework
Nested=Frameworks/Syphon.framework
Nested=Frameworks/QtGui.framework
Nested=Frameworks/QtMultimedia.framework
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqgif.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqico.dylib
Nested=Frameworks/fftreal.framework
Nested=PlugIns/printsupport/libcocoaprintersupport.dylib
Nested=Frameworks/QtXml.framework
Nested=PlugIns/bearer/libqgenericbearer.dylib
Nested=Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework
Nested=PlugIns/bearer/libqcorewlanbearer.dylib
Nested=Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework
Nested=PlugIns/imageformats/libqwebp.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
```

Here is the script I use to sign the package :

```
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Macdeployqt et copie de Syphon"
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
${QT_BIN_PATH}/macdeployqt ${PATH_BIN} -verbose=3
cp -Rf /Users/digitalessence/Downloads/Syphon\ SDK\ Public\ Beta\ 2/Syphon.framework  ${PATH_FRAMEWORK}/.

echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Modification of Qt path"
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Modification of HeavyM libs path "
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/HeavyM
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Signature of app"
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
codesign --no-strict --deep --force --verify --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: Digital Essence" ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/fftreal.framework/fftreal
codesign --no-strict --deep --force --verify --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: Digital Essence" ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/Qt*.framework/Qt*
codesign --no-strict --deep --force --verify --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: Digital Essence" ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/Frameworks/Syphon.framework/Syphon
codesign --no-strict --deep --force --verify --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: Digital Essence" ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/PlugIns/*/*
codesign --no-strict --deep --force --verify --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: Digital Essence" ${PATH_BIN}/Contents/MacOS/*
codesign --no-strict --sign "Developer ID Application: Digital Essence" --deep --verbose=4  ${PATH_BIN}
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Verify application signing"
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
codesign --deep --verify --verbose=4 -d ${PATH_BIN}
spctl --verbose=4 --assess --type execute ${PATH_BIN} && dropdmg --config-name=heavym ${PATH_BIN}
echo -------------------------FINISHED-------------------------------
```

Anyone as an idea about what can cause this problem or anyone is facing the same problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need run `codesign` 6 times?  Once (on the `.app`) should be fine with `--deep`.

Comment: I wanted to be sure that everything is well-signed . I know the flag `--deep` should be enough but I tried every option to make this works. Both doesn't work after uploading the app.

Comment: The script is also overly long and very brittle.  Why not search for frameworks/dylibs in the app and then run `install_name_tool` based on the name of the thing you've found; there is no need to have an explicit line for every framework.  This is *far* less error prone and easier to maintain.